# MySql получение схемы GetSchemaTable

Tags: c#, mysql

Запрос к бд, создаю таблицу на основе ее схемы. Хочу тут же записать данные в созданную таблицу.

Код программы:

```
        DataTable tbl=new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect))
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConn);
            dbConn.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                tbl = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
                while (rdr.Read())
                    foreach (DataRow rw in tbl.Rows)
                        for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            rw[i] = rdr.GetString(i);
                        }
            }

        }
```

На выходе получаю что схема таблицы будто переворачивается. Строки становятся именами таблицы, а колонками становиться что-то непонятное.

Comment: А разве не проще сразу напрямую в запросе сделать таблицу на основе существующей? типа `CREATE TABLE new_table 
SELECT col, col2, col3 
FROM
    existing_table;`

Comment: Не совсем  тебя понял, мне нужно готовую таблицу из базы mysql скопировать в программу.

Comment: я подумал что ты одну таблицу хотел в другую перенести. Не совсем понял